# Why don't discriminated unions in typescript work in this way?

Tags: typescript

Why can't typescript discriminate based on a common property like this?
After reading [the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) I thought this would work.

Heres a [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20Mammal%20%3D%20%7B%20legs%3A%20number%20%7D%0D%0Atype%20Fish%20%3D%20%7B%20fins%3A%20number%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Action1%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20'a'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20payload%3A%20Mammal%20%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Action2%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20'b'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20payload%3A%20Fish%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20ActionUnion%20%3D%20Action1%20%7C%20Action2%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20A%3A%20Action1%20%3D%20%7B%20type%3A%20'a'%2C%20payload%3A%20%7B%20legs%3A%204%20%7D%20%7D%0D%0Aconst%20B%3A%20Action2%20%3D%20%7B%20type%3A%20'b'%2C%20payload%3A%20%7B%20fins%3A%203%20%7D%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20foo(action%3A%20ActionUnion)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20switch%20(action.type)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20case%20'a'%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20%7B%20legs%20%7D%20%3D%20action.payload%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20case%20'b'%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20%7B%20fins%20%7D%20%3D%20action.payload%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20default%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20break%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A)

```
type Mammal = { legs: number }
type Fish = { fins: number }

type Action1 = {
    type: 'a',
    payload: Mammal 
}


type Action2 = {
    type: 'b',
    payload: Fish
}

type ActionUnion = Action1 | Action2

const A: Action1 = { type: 'a', payload: { legs: 4 } }
const B: Action2 = { type: 'b', payload: { fins: 3 } }

function foo(action: ActionUnion) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'a':
            const { legs } = action.payload

        case 'b':
            const { fins } = action.payload

        default:
            break
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You forgot to break your case statement. Should look like this

```
case 'a':
    const { legs } = action.payload
    break;
case 'b':
    const { fins } = action.payload
```

Comment: Massive face palm.

Comment: @hally9k It's midnight. You are forgiven.

Answer (score 2):

They do work like that, but your switch case was falling through to the next case, add a `break` and it will work

```
type Mammal = { legs: number }
type Fish = { fins: number }

type Action1 = {
    type: 'a',
    payload: Mammal 
}


type Action2 = {
    type: 'b',
    payload: Fish
}

type ActionUnion = Action1 | Action2

const A: Action1 = { type: 'a', payload: { legs: 4 } }
const B: Action2 = { type: 'b', payload: { fins: 3 } }

function foo(action: ActionUnion) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'a':
            const { legs } = action.payload
            break;
        case 'b':
            const { fins } = action.payload
            break;
        default:
            break
    } 
}
```